# Regex (sed) that may need to capture multiple expressions per line

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I am trying to write a regex that will capture the a name in a file, where some lines may have 2 or more names that need to be captured.

For example, I would like to take a file with:

```
Field_1 \t Field_2 \t Field_3 \t JGN;Name=hsa-123;J4N9;Name=cfa-241-b
Field_1 \t Field_2 \t Field_3 \t JPN;Name=hsa-1323;JJ39;Name=cfa-255-b;Name=hsa-188
```

And have an output file return:

```
Field_1 \t Field_2 \t Field_3 \t hsa-123; cfa-241-b
Field_1 \t Field_2 \t Field_3 \t hsa-1323;cfa-255-b;hsa-188
```

I am using the regex as follows:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t.*\;Name=\(.*\);.*/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\;\4/g'
```

But this only returns the first name.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does

```
sed 's/\([[:space:]]\|;\)[[:alnum:]]*;/\1/g; s/Name=//g'
```

work for you?

Comment: Well, he/she also wants to remove JGN; JPN; etc.

Comment: @miono Thanks, I misread that part, thought those were the same. Fixin'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right :) Noticed that as well. The answer's under construction. Sorry.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully, I haven't missed anything this time.

Comment: Perfect.  I appreciate your help.  Been spending quite a bit of time on this one.  Humbling

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E 's/ [^ ;]+;//; s/;[^=]+;/;/g; s/Name=//g' file
Field_1 \t Field_2 \t Field_3 \thsa-123;cfa-241-b
Field_1 \t Field_2 \t Field_3 \thsa-1323;cfa-255-b;hsa-188
```

If your sed doesn't supprrt EREs (-E) then change [^ ;]+ to [^ ;][^ ;]* and [^=]+ to [^=][^=]* or use awk with [g]sub().